# How to deploy website in windows EC2 IIS server with host name?

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2

How to deploy a website in Windows ec2 iis server, I put the code in `C\inetpub\wwwroot`, and it works while using EC2 local IP address but when I add the name of the host to the IIS server, then it does not work.

I already add port `80` in firewall.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html it does not work because you set a wrong binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Amazon VPC console at [https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/]

**1)** In the navigation pane, choose **Security Groups**.

**2)** Select the security group to update. ...

**3)** On the **Inbound Rules tab**, choose Edit the **port range** 80, 443 - **Source**: Anywhere - **IP Address**: 0.0.0.0/0

**4)** Optionally provide a description for the rule, and **choose Save**.